# Disable parallel express route access

Tags: node.js, express, redis

I have gotten a task which requires me to create a route which sends a request to another api, now the thing is that i must only allow 1 query to the other api even if 10 people access my route at the exact time.
I was requested to perform it with redis but a part from just caching the data im having a hard time finding out how to block all other requests from querying the other api. ( assume all requests happen in parallel)